# Magma - Differential field extension over a differential field

Tags: symbolic-math, magma-ca

I want to construct the differential field Q(x, log x, log(log x)) in Magma.

I have tried the following:

```
> F<x> := RationalDifferentialField(RationalField());
> G<ln> := LogarithmicFieldExtension(F, 1/x);
> L<lln> := LogarithmicFieldExtension(G, G!(1/(x*ln)));
```

I find, as expected, that `BaseField(F)` is `G`. However, Magma has set the derivative of `lln` to be the same as that of `ln`; moreover, they are equal:

```
> Derivative(lln);
1/x
> lln eq ln;
true
```

I have the same issue when I employ an identical method to try to construct Q(x log(x + 1), log(x - 1)). The generator of any extension after the first always has the same derivative as the generator of the first extension.

I did some investigating in the source code in `package/Ring/RngDiff/RngDiff.m` and the implementation of `LogarithmicFieldExtension` essentially just calls `DifferentialRingExtension` with the appropriate argument. I can use this intrinsic to construct Q(x log(x + 1), log(x - 1)) as follows:

```
> P := PolynomialRing(F, 2);
> G<ln1, ln2> := DifferentialRingExtension([P | 1/(x-1), 1/(x+1)]);
> Derivative(ln1); Derivative(ln2);
1/(x - 1)
1/(x + 1)
```

However, the following construction has the same problem as the initial example using `LogarithmicFieldExtension` (therefore the problem is not in `LogarithmicFieldExtension`, but in `DifferentialRingExtension`):

```
> G := DifferentialRingExtension([PolynomialRing(F, 1) | 1/(x+1)]);
> L := DifferentialRingExtension([PolynomialRing(G, 1) | 1/(x-1)]);
> BaseRing(L) eq G;
true
> L.1 eq G.1;
true
```

Unfortunately, because the input to `DifferentialRingExtension` must be of type `[RngMPolElt]`, I can't construct log(log x) as this would require the argument to `DifferentialRingExtension` to be `[P | 1/x, 1/(x*P.1)]`. I actually need to construct an extension over an existing extension field.

Is there some error I have made in my constructions using `DifferentialRingExtension` which is preventing it from working the way I expect? If this is a bug in Magma, is there a way to work around it so that I can construct Q(x, log x, log(log x))? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Mitchell, that's an interesting question, although I wonder if there will be enough knowledgeable people in the audience here at SO to answer it. You might need to look for a Magma-specific forum or mailing list; I don't know what that might be. You could also try math.stackexchange.com, which is a larger, though also not Magma-specific, forum.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDodier. I haven't been able to find any Magma-specific forums or mailing lists unfortunately. If anyone knows of any I would be very appreciative and eager to post on them.

Comment: Hmm, the user forum for the Sage software system (https://www.sagemath.org/) has at least one person who has used Magma, I think. I know that's a stretch.